# AngularJS 1.5, attributes in component isn t recovered

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I know this post [Angular 1.5 component attribute presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438408/angular-1-5-component-attribute-presence) should answer my question but I did everything like they did and I still can t recovered my data! If you have any idea why.. :)

**Component:**

```
component('ficheOperation', {
    templateUrl : 'operations/creerOperation.template.html',
    bindings : {
      idOp : '<'
    },
    controller : ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location',
      function ficheOperationController($scope, $routeParams, $location){
        var self = this;
        console.log(self.idOp);
    }]
})
```

**HTML :**

```
<fiche-operation idOp="33"></fiche-operation>
```

the template is rightfully loaded but in my console all I get is a horrific "undefined".

**Thx**

Comment: have you tried console.log(self)? could show something useful..

Comment: It show the object containing idOp but as undefined, really weird, if I find what is wrong I will update this

Comment: I don't think naming the function makes sense here. `ficheOperationController` could be causing your issue. It should be just `function($scope, $routeParams, $location)`

Comment: I tried after removing "ficheOperationController", it just work the same, fine but without retrieving the attribute but Thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem I encountered in your code was the binding name you used in the template, you have to use it as `id-op="33"` instead of `idOp="33"`.

```
<fiche-operation id-op="33"></fiche-operation>
```

Also, you won't be able to see the binding property before the component has gotten fully initialized. Therefore, you have to make use of the `$onInit` life cycle hook.

```
this.$onInit = function() {
    console.log(self.idOp);
};
```

I made a small app with a component based on your code which fix the errors I found in it.

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .component('ficheOperation', {
    template: '{{ $ctrl.idOp }}',
    bindings: {
      idOp: '<'
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$location',
      function ficheOperationController($scope, $location) {
        var self = this;

        self.$onInit = function() {
          console.log(self.idOp);
        };
      }
    ]
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <fiche-operation id-op="33"></fiche-operation>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
```

### Refs

[Understanding Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

[Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Ahah thx a lot, shame on me for idOp but didn't t know this self.$onInit! I would have up voted it but I don t have enough point ^^

Comment: voted for you @artlessboy, glad to know this so i can avoid it when i face it ;)